# Solidity says my function can by marked as view but my code changes state?

Tags: solidity, solc, view

Given the code below, when I compile the code with Remix it says the function *processBandPayments()* can be marked as **view**.  This concerns me greatly since in my mind, the code is changing state by altering the content of one or the other storage variables; in this case the *claims* or *escrow* storage variable.

So either this is a Solc/Remix bug (doubtful) or my code doesn't do what I think it does and doesn't really record payments or escrow assignments to the blockchain.  Can anyone shed some light on this?

```
// The map that maps a game ID to a specific game.
mapping(uint256 => structGame) public s_mapGameIdToGame;

// The map that maps a request nonce to a game ID.
mapping (address => uint256) public s_mapRequestNonceToGameId;

// The map that tracks how much Ether is due to a particular address, whether that 
//  address is a player or a band.
mapping (address => uint256) public s_mapAddressToClaimAmount;

// The map that tracks how much Ether is due to a paritcular owner ID.  This is the 
//  "escrow" storage.
mapping (bytes32 => uint256) public s_mapOwnerIdToEscrowAmount;

// The round of each play in a game is stored here.
mapping (uint256 => structGameRoundResults[]) public s_mapGameIdToGameResults;

/**
 * @notice Process the payments to the band using the results of the game given 
 *  to us earlier by multiple calls to addGameRoundResult().
 * 
 * NOTE: If an address is not found in the band addresses array, the amount due that 
 *  band is stored in the escrow map instead of the claims map.
 * 
 * param _perBandPayment - The amount to pay each band.
 */
function processBandPayments(
        uint256 _gameId, 
        uint256 _perBandPayment
    )
        private 
        onlyIfValidGameId(_gameId) onlyIfPlayingState(_gameId) {

    // We should have at least one game round result or something is 
    //  very wrong.
    require(s_mapGameIdToGameResults[_gameId].length > 0, "(processBandPayments) The game round results array is empty.");

    // If the band donation percentage is 0, then this method should not have been called.
    require(_perBandPayment > 0, "(processBandPayments) The payment for each band is 0.");

    // Process each band payment by iterating the game round results.
    for (uint i = 0; i < s_mapGameIdToGameResults[_gameId].length; i++)
    {
        require(s_mapGameIdToGameResults[_gameId][i].ownerId.length > 0, "(processBandPayments) An owner ID was not set.");

        // Do we have a band address?
        if (s_mapGameIdToGameResults[_gameId][i].bandAddr == address(0)) {
            // No.  Aggregate the payment amount in escrow.
            s_mapOwnerIdToEscrowAmount[s_mapGameIdToGameResults[_gameId][i].ownerId].add(_perBandPayment);
        }
        else {
            // Yes.  Aggregate the payment.
            s_mapAddressToClaimAmount[s_mapGameIdToGameResults[_gameId][i].bandAddr].add(_perBandPayment);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it is from the SafeMath library, the `.add(...)` function returns the values added together, but does not modify the storage value. You will have to put (for example):

`storageArray[index] = storageArray[index].add(amountToAdd);`

Comment: Ouch.  Yeah.  I've been banging my head against that one lately.  Thanks.